# How to ensure that a python dict keys are lowercase?

Tags: python, json, simplejson, django-piston

I have a dict that I want to convert in JSON using simplejson.

How can I ensure that all the keys of my dict are lowercase ?

```
    {
        "DISTANCE": 17.059918745802999, 
        "name": "Foo Bar", 
        "Restaurant": {
            "name": "Foo Bar", 
            "full_address": {
                "country": "France", 
                "street": "Foo Bar", 
                "zip_code": "68190", 
                "city": "UNGERSHEIM"
            }, 
            "phone": "+33.389624300", 
            "longitude": "7.3064454", 
            "latitude": "47.8769091", 
            "id": "538"
        }, 
        "price": "", 
        "composition": "", 
        "profils": {}, 
        "type_menu": "", 
        "ID": ""
    },
```

EDIT: Thanks all to had a look at my question, I am sorry I didn't explain in detailed why I wanted this. It was to patch the `JSONEmitter` of `django-piston`.

Comment: To ensure they are lowercase they must be lowercase. Create a dict with lowercase keys.

Comment: What do you mean by "ensure"? Do you have and existing dict and do you want to check whether all keys are lowercase? Or convert them all to lowercase? Or do you want to create a kind of dict that only allows lowercase keys (when inserting them)?

Comment: As you can see in the example, some of the keys are not lowercase. I want to be sure that every JSON key are lowercase.

Comment: "some of the keys are not lowercase"  Why not?  Was your editor broken?  What stopped you from fixing them?

Comment: The dictionary is automaticaly generated by `django-piston` and to be sure that the models fields are rewrite with the cls_method of the handler, I need to put them uppercase. When I convert the dictionnary in JSON I need to make sure that the key are all lowercase.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
>>> d = {"your": "DATA", "FROM": "above"}
>>> dict((k.lower(), v) for k, v in d.iteritems())
{'from': 'above', 'your': 'DATA'}
>>> def lower_keys(x):
...   if isinstance(x, list):
...     return [lower_keys(v) for v in x]
...   elif isinstance(x, dict):
...     return dict((k.lower(), lower_keys(v)) for k, v in x.iteritems())
...   else:
...     return x
...
>>> lower_keys({"NESTED": {"ANSWER": 42}})
{'nested': {'answer': 42}}
```

Comment: I only picked up that you want nested dicts and lists treated specially from your self-answer; normally I would handle this at a different level.

Comment: On python 3 you can use comprehension and won't need the `dict(...)` --> `d = {k.lower(): v for k, v in d.items()}`

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution that forbids setting a lowercase key:

```
class LowerCaseDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        if not key.islower():
            raise TypeError, "%s key must be lowercase" % key
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, val)

ld = LowerCaseDict()
ld['g']='g'
```

Comment: Or, just have `__setitem__` do `dict.__setitem__(self, key.lower(), val)`. The problem with this approach in general is that the constructor and `.update` don't use __setitem__ - you'll need to work around that, or `LowerCaseDict({'Foo': 1, 'bar': 2})` wouldn't act as expected (won't lowercase it for my way or won't raise a TypeError for your way).

Comment: You also have to make sure to also use LowerCaseDict for every nested dict.

Comment: This implementation is incomplete as it does not properly cover the creation of the dictionary. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27889931/99834 for a working solution.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my solution :

```
def lower_key(in_dict):
    if type(in_dict) is dict:
        out_dict = {}
        for key, item in in_dict.items():
            out_dict[key.lower()] = lower_key(item)
        return out_dict
    elif type(in_dict) is list:
        return [lower_key(obj) for obj in in_dict]
    else:
        return in_dict
```

Comment: Nice recursive solution, to handle the issue after "the fact".

Answer (score 4):

Since you have not mentioned clearly what you want to do:

Convert all keys to lowercase:

```
>>> y = dict((k.lower(), v) for k, v in x.iteritems())
```

Check for keys:

```
>>> for k in x.iterkeys():
    if k.islower():
        print k, 'True'
    else:
        print k, 'False'
```

Comment: The problem with .iteritems() and .iterkeys() is that they're not recursive.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a complete solution

```
from requests import CaseInsensitiveDict
```

Or if you want to see the code:

```
class CaseInsensitiveDict(dict):

    """Basic case insensitive dict with strings only keys."""

    proxy = {}

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.proxy = dict((k.lower(), k) for k in data)
        for k in data:
            self[k] = data[k]

    def __contains__(self, k):
        return k.lower() in self.proxy

    def __delitem__(self, k):
        key = self.proxy[k.lower()]
        super(CaseInsensitiveDict, self).__delitem__(key)
        del self.proxy[k.lower()]

    def __getitem__(self, k):
        key = self.proxy[k.lower()]
        return super(CaseInsensitiveDict, self).__getitem__(key)

    def get(self, k, default=None):
        return self[k] if k in self else default

    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        super(CaseInsensitiveDict, self).__setitem__(k, v)
        self.proxy[k.lower()] = k
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to *check* if they're all lowercase (your wording, using "ensure", is not clear, but I suspect this isn't what you want), you can do that compactly in one line:

```
all(k.islower() for k in x.iterkeys())
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `python-benedict` (a `dict` subclass) and **standardize** your instance to convert all string keys to `snake_case`.

```
from benedict import benedict

d = benedict({
    "DISTANCE": 17.059918745802999, 
    "name": "Foo Bar", 
    "Restaurant": {
        "name": "Foo Bar", 
        "full_address": {
            "country": "France", 
            "street": "Foo Bar", 
            "zip_code": "68190", 
            "city": "UNGERSHEIM"
        }, 
        "phone": "+33.389624300", 
        "longitude": "7.3064454", 
        "latitude": "47.8769091", 
        "id": "538"
    }, 
    "price": "", 
    "composition": "", 
    "profils": {}, 
    "type_menu": "", 
    "ID": ""
})

# convert all string keys to snake_case (nested dict keys included)
d.standardize()
```

and your `dict` will become:

```py
{
    "distance": 17.059918745802999, 
    "name": "Foo Bar", 
    "restaurant": {
        "name": "Foo Bar", 
        "full_address": {
            "country": "France", 
            "street": "Foo Bar", 
            "zip_code": "68190", 
            "city": "UNGERSHEIM"
        }, 
        "phone": "+33.389624300", 
        "longitude": "7.3064454", 
        "latitude": "47.8769091", 
        "id": "538"
    }, 
    "price": "", 
    "composition": "", 
    "profils": {}, 
    "type_menu": "", 
    "id": ""
})
```

Installation: `pip install python-benedict`

Documentation: https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/python-benedict

Note: I am the author of this project

Answer (score 1):

another adaptation to handle the values:

```
def lower_keys(x):
        if isinstance(x, str):
                return (x.lower())
        if isinstance(x, list):
                return [lower_keys(v) for v in x]
        elif isinstance(x, dict):
                return dict((k.lower(), lower_keys(v)) for k, v in x.items())
        else:
                return x
```